# Visualizar imágenes en laravel usando Response

Tags: html, css, laravel-5, bootstrap

Estoy tratando de visualizar una imagen en una nueva ventana

En el Controlador

```
 public function getDownload(Request $request){    
    $file=public_path("storage/pictures/".$request->namefile);
    return response()->download($file);

}
```

En Vista

```
 <a target="_blank" href="{{route("admin.equipment.case.download",['namefile'=>$pictures->name_random_file_imagen])}}" class="mt-1 d-inline-block">DESCARGAR</a>
```

Estoy tratando de utilizar  target="_blank" pero no me lo muestra en otra ventana, simplemente me los descarga.

Comment: Y si usas return response()->file($file);

Comment: ya traté pero sigue igual

Comment: Si funcionó @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas la razón de que no funcionaba es que antes lo estaba probando con una imagen que ya tenía, Me funciono hasta que subí otra imagen nueva, Por que sera que sucede eso???

Comment: pero funciono con tu ->download o con el stream ???

Comment: Me funcionó con el stream

Comment: Mira ver si te funciona mi respuesta de ser positivo marcala como correcta ;P

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas Aclaro las imágenes que antes  tenía con download($file); cuando cambié a stream no funcionan se siguen descargando y las que subí DESPUES si  funcionan.

Comment: prueba con ->file

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
public function getDownload(Request $request){    
  $file=public_path("storage/pictures/".$request->namefile);
  return response()->file($file);
}
```

Con respecto a lo que comentastes en tu comentario que funciono a la primera pero no a la segunda vez pk era la misma imagen mira ver si jugando con los headers que se le pasa a la funcion stream puedes resolverlo, qui te dejo el link:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-52-responsestream-alternative

Seria algo como construir un arreglo con los headers como este:

```
$headers = [
    'Cache-Control'       => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
    'Content-type'        => 'image/png',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=image01.png',
    'Expires'             => '0',
    'Pragma'              => 'public',
];
```

donde content-type sea el mimetype de tu archivo y en content disposition pongas el nombre del archivo con su extension y esta variable se la pases a stream

```
response()->file($file, $headers);
```